# Prism-MEF: how to navigate to view in different module using UriQuey

Tags: prism, mef

if i have this module structure:

```
ModuleA
      *View/View_A
      *Controller/ControllerA
ModuleB
      *View/View_B
      *ViewModel/ViewModel_B  (view model for View_B)
      *Controller/Controller_B
```

1. how could ControllerA use UriQuery to display View_B in a region
   inside View_A
2. how could controllerB use UriQuery to display View_B in a region
   inside View_A
3. which is better for displaying View_B in a region in View_A

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I answer your question exactly. But I would recommend you to take a look at the Sample project that came with Prism2.2 -> Quickstarts - > UI Composition -> View Injection. This uses Unity and the example is in Silverlight and WPF.

This has the sample of how you can show the view from different module. It does not call the controller of the other project but calls the presenter.

```
 IProjectsListPresenter projectsListPresenter = this.container.Resolve<IProjectsListPresenter>();
 projectsListPresenter.SetProjects(employee.EmployeeId);

 IRegionManager detailsRegionManager = detailsRegion.Add(detailsPresenter.View, employee.EmployeeId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), true);
 IRegion region = detailsRegionManager.Regions[RegionNames.TabRegion];
 region.Add(projectsListPresenter.View, "CurrentProjectsView");
 detailsRegion.Activate(detailsPresenter.View);
```

Use the activate method to activate the view. Or if it is specific requirement/need to navigate, you can use detailsRegionManager.RequestNavigate with the UriQuery. (I have not tried request navigate myself :)

Additionally please review this post

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/402860#post940396

Hope this helps.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for your help but i'm using MEF so i use view export not view injection and i use UriQuery() and RequestNavigate to navigate to a view which lie in another module. maybe the problem in the path passed to uri.

Comment: <root directory>\Prism\Quickstarts\View-Switching Navigation\Silverlight\View-Switching Navigation has samples with MEF and navigation. Look at the ContactsViewModel calling ComposeEmailView.